# Accessing a method with parameters from a different class

Tags: java, class, netbeans, methods, parameters

I'm sorry if this is an easy question, but I can't seem to call my one method with parameters from another class.

Normally if I were to call my method, I would do it by it like so.

Class1

```
public static void main(String [] args){
   Class2 class2Object = new Class2();
   class2Object.myMethod();
}
```

Class2

```
public void myMethod(){
  System.out.print("Hello");
}
```

The above is just an example, but if I had to pass a parameter into the myMethod method (for example an arrayList), how would I call it in my other class.

The actual method I need to call is below:

```
public void search(List<String> listOfWords) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException
```

Any help will be appreciated,
Regards.

Comment: What did you try? What are you having trouble with?

Comment: Found my error, don't worry.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You simply put a list in the arguments of the method when calling it:

```
List<String> someList = new ArrayList<String>();
//populate list if you want
class2Object.search(someList);
```

You would probably benefit from reading [a tutorial on methods arguments](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/arguments.html).

Comment: That's what originally tried, but it either returns an error or automatically changes `class2Object.search(someList);`; to `class2Object.search(null);` . Think I have found my error. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
Class2 class2Object = new Class2();
List<String> myList = new List<String>();
class2Object.search(myList);
```

Answer (score 1):

You add the information you want to pass in call and the data type and what you want to refer to it as in the definition

```
public static void main(String [] args){
  Class2 class2Object = new Class2();
  class2Object.myMethod(5);
}

public void myMethod(int var){
  System.out.print(var);
}
```